# Why is my recvfrom function from Winsock so slow even with a timeout?

Tags: winsock

I have a basic UDP server that's using blocking calls with timeouts.

I set the timeouts using

```
int timeout = 1; 

setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(int));
```

Then I have a while loop with nothing else in there except from

```
while (1)
    {
        printf("receiving...");
        int ret = recvfrom(serverSocket, (char*)buffer, 1024, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen);
    }
```

But there seems to be a ridiculous delay between each printf and it's definitely coming from `recvfrom`. Removing this line entirely  makes the application speed up.

Everything is hosted locally so there should be no lag.

The code returned is correct and is a `WSAETIMEDOUT (10060)` but the timings are not correct! A 1ms timeout should not take around 400ms.

How can I get rid of this delay?

Comment: `setsockopt(q, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&c, sizeof(c));
 setsockopt(q, 6, 18, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));  `    also

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: remove from and fromlen. that's what i'll undertake

Comment: also try all that after connect

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this is happening so I will leave the question open.

For now I have switched to using `select()` for the timeout and this works as expected.